# jQuery image fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code. When it changes the image, the image fades out and then the other image fades in, and in the meanwhile I can see the background color, which I don't want to see. Is there any simple way to fade images but at the same time fade in the next image, or another jQuery effect like slide the images? I just don't want to see the background color.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgArr = new Array( // relative paths of images
        'css/images/main_img.jpg',
        'css/images/main_img_2.jpg',
        'css/images/main_img_3.jpg',
        'css/images/main_img_4.jpg',
        'css/images/main_img_5.jpg'
    );

    var preloadArr = new Array();
    var i;

    /* preload images */
    for(i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
        preloadArr[i] = new Image();
        preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
    }

    var currImg = 1;
    var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 6000);
    //added this so that the first image is always the first from the array
    $('#main_content').css('background','url(' + preloadArr[0].src +') top center no-repeat');
    /* Main IMG */
    function changeImg(){
        $('#main_content').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
            $(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') top center no-repeat');
        }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try a cross fade like this: http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Comment: @JohnKoerner the demo looks neat, I am going to give it a try thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the css background you can't do this against a single element.

You could achieve this with another div which would hold the next background image (before your content fades out) and would be put under your #main_content element using none static css position states and z-index property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this effect with one element only. You need a second element on top of the other and fade it in. Once its faded in, you can hide the back element but it's not even necessary.

See this tutotrial: http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written codes for creating simple JavaScript fade effect animation using Jquery, which may help you to create awesome image animations.

At first add the following script to import jquery.min.js or you can host this script yourself.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Here write CSS codes for

.fade and .fade img

```
.fade 
{ 
box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 2px #6DC83C; 
position:relative; 
width:500px; 
height: 300px; 
border-radius:19px; 
} 

.fade img 
{ 
border-radius:19px; 
position:absolute; 
left:0;
top:0; 
}
```

And use the following Code.

```
<script> $(function(){ $('.fade img:gt(0)').hide(); setInterval(function(){$('.fade    :first-child').fadeOut(3000).next('img').fadeIn(3000).end().appendTo('.fade');}, 4000); });    </script>
```

Then use the following code for images.

```
<div class="fade"> 
<img src="image_1.gif"> 
<img src="image_2.gif"> 
<img src="image_3.gif"> 
</div>
```